# Argument passing during object initialisation (Python OOP)

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance

Im a student developer and am studying for an upcoming test. Ive been working on a practice question on Inheritance and Polymorphism and managed to achieve the expected results, but i don't seem to understand my own code after attempting to analyse it thoroughly. I want to create a Superclass 'Player', and initialise objects from the superclass to essentially create basketball players and form them into a team before displaying the team members using the **str** method. Below is the code for Player.py:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, player_name):
        self.player_name = player_name

    def get_player_name(self):
        return self.player_name

    def set_player_name(self, player_name):
        self.player_name = player_name


class BasketballPlayer(Player):

    positions = ['Guard', 'Forward', 'Center']

    def __init__(self, player_name):
        super().__init__(player_name)
        self.player_position = None

    def get_player_position(self):
        return self.player_position

    def set_player_position(self, player_position):
        self.player_position = player_position
        if self.player_position not in BasketballPlayer.positions:
            print("Invalid position for basketball player.")
            self.player_position = ""

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.get_player_name()} playing as a {self.player_position}"
```

And below is the code for my Test Program where I execute my functions:

```
from Player import *                                                                              
                                                                                                  
                                                                                                  
List_of_players = []                                                                              
team_name = str(input("Please enter the basketball team name: "))                                 
                                                                                                  
for i in range(5):                                                                                
    player_name = str(input("Please enter player name: "))                                        
    player_position = str(input("Please enter the basketball player's position: "))               
                                                                                                  
    BasketBallPlayer_obj = BasketballPlayer(player_name)                                          
                                                                                                  
    BasketBallPlayer_obj.set_player_position(player_position)                                     
    BasketBallPlayer_obj.set_player_name(player_name)                                             
                                                                                                  
    List_of_players.append(BasketBallPlayer_obj)                                                  
                                                                                                  
print(f"Team {team_name} consists of the following players: ")                                    
for i in range(len(List_of_players)):                                                             
    print(List_of_players[i])
```

I'm using a for loop to iterate through creating a basketball player object 5 times for 5 players. Could someone help explain to me why there is a need to pass in a 'player_name' argument when initialising the `BasketBallPlayer_obj` in `BasketBallPlayer_obj = BasketballPlayer(player_name)`? I get a TypeError if i remove the argument passing and can't figure out why I need to pass the 'player_name' argument in, thank you so much in advance for answering this question!

I tried removing the 'player_name' argument when initialising the object but it threw a TypeError saying that "Player.**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'player_name'".

Comment: because that is how you defined `BasketBallPlayer.__init__`... it requires that argument. Which is fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your definition for the `__init__` method:

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, player_name):
        self.player_name = player_name
```

In that definition, your code states that in order to create a new `Player` object, you must pass a `player_name`.

As such, if you attempt to initialise a `Player` without providing that data, it will fail.

As for why it fails when removing it from the `BasketballPlayer`'s `__init__` method, you'll notice that that method calls `super().__init__(player_name)`. If you remove the requirement from `BasketballPlayer`, but not from `Player`, the `__init__` call will fail, since initialising an object requires calling the `__init__` function of all classes it inherits from.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be better like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, player_name):
        self.player_name = player_name

    @property
    def player_name(self):
        return self._player_name

    @player_name.setter
    def player_name(self, val):
        self._player_name = val


positions = ['Guard', 'Forward', 'Center']


class BasketballPlayer(Player):

    def __init__(self, player_position, player_name):
        super().__init__(player_name)
        self.player_position = player_position

    @property
    def player_position(self):
        return self._player_position

    @player_position.setter
    def player_position(self, value):
        if value in positions:
            self._player_position = value
        else:
            print("Invalid position for basketball player.")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.player_name} playing as {self.player_position}"


List_of_players = []
team_name = str(input("Please enter the basketball team name: "))

for i in range(5):
    name = str(input("Please enter player name: "))
    playerposition = str(input("Please enter the basketball player's position: "))
    BasketBallPlayer_obj = BasketballPlayer(player_name=name, player_position=playerposition)
    List_of_players.append(BasketBallPlayer_obj)

print(f"Team {team_name} consists of the following players: ")
for i in range(len(List_of_players)):
    print(List_of_players[i])
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: When you initialize arguments in your class, you have to pass them when you call your Class to create objects. I just provided you with better style to pass arguments. No need to call methods in your Class.

Comment: I did not ask the question. I am merely pointing out that your answer doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: you are right. I tried to make it better in the OOP coding style.